# What are the requirements for running a Solana Archive Node (not validator)?

Tags: rpc

I'd like to run an Archive Node (not a Validator one), and was wondering whether I may find the specific documentation on this one.

1. What are the hardware requirements / specifications for running an Archive Node? We're a Solana RPC provider, not an individual user?
2. Is it possible to run/deploy an Archive node via a hardware server, not a cloud one?

Answer (score 2):

i believe that Archive Node is not a Solana real thing but a Coinbase product announced but without further information, reference info:

https://forums.coinbasecloud.dev/t/solana-archive-node/1244